# Create2 - Sending ether to not yet existing smart contract

Tags: merkle-patricia-tries, create2

I'm trying to understand the `create2` opcode to deploy a smart contract. As we can predict the address of newly created smart contract, it is possible to send ETH to non yet existing smart contract and then, control the ETH later after the deployment.

My question is: during the process of sending ETH to non yet existing smart contract, at the low level, I would expect the EVM will try to look up for the destination address (the non yet existing smart contract's address) in the Patricia Merkle Tree to update the balance, but since the account doesn't exist, it wouldn't find the corresponding leaf node, will the EVM at this moment create the leaf node and after the contract's deployment, it will fill the remaining account information (Code hash, Storage Hash, Nonce) ? Or it will try to do something else.
I'm confused because I know the transaction will proceed without errors, but the contract's address doesn't exist yet, and this is not a burn scenario.

Comment: Yes it is possible to send eth to any non-existing address. Unfortunately don't know the exact technical details how it works.

Comment: Do you want to edit or post a new question if you want to know low-level what data structures are created or updated when ether is sent to an address? Otherwise when ether is sent to an address the first time, it doesn't matter whether the address is a CREATE2 address or not: the EVM doesn't know at that point. At high-level what you said sounds good. You may be interested in looking around https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-161.md